# iOS background post request on silent notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, request, background

I want to ask if it's even possible to **send URL POST request** from app when app receive **silent push notification**. If it is possible how can I get it?

My application successfully receiving silent push notifications and **when I have my phone plugged in Xcode I'm able to execute url task** (even in background) and get the desired results. **After unplugging the phone from my Mac, the phone stops executing url tasks** at all.

Regarding the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns#2947607), when silent push notification appears, I have 30 seconds to execute the code

> Your app has 30 seconds to perform any tasks and call the provided completion handler

My silent push notification:

```
{
   notification: {},
   apns: {
      headers: {
          "apns-priority" : '5',
          "apns-push-type" : 'background'
      },
      payload: {
          aps: {
              "content-available" : 1,
          }
      }
   },
   topic: topic
};
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    
    guard (userInfo["aps"] as? [String?: Any]) != nil else {
        Analytics.logEvent("fetch_failed", parameters: nil)
        completionHandler(.failed)
        return
    }
    
    self.emailFetch() // Here I call my function for sending POST request via URLSession
    
    print(userInfo)
    
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

**SOLVED**

Currently I have updated dataTask to downloadTask and now I am able to successfully read the answer from the server from temporary file. It works properly when the app is running in background.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    guard (userInfo["aps"] as? [String?: Any]) != nil else {
        Analytics.logEvent("fetch_failed", parameters: nil)
        completionHandler(.failed)
        return
    }
   

    if login != nil && password != nil {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: "https://....")!
        let body_values = Data(("data...").utf8)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        request.httpBody = body_values
        
        print("Starting load data")

        let loadDataTask = session.downloadTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print(httpResponse.statusCode)
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                    if let data = data {
                        if let dataString = try? String(contentsOf: data) {
                         This is being executed only in XCode
                         My logic is here...

                            
                            completionHandler(.newData)
                        } else {
                            completionHandler(.failed)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        completionHandler(.failed)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    completionHandler(.failed)
                }
            }
            else {
                completionHandler(.failed)
            }
        }
        loadDataTask.resume()
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(.failed)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did you found a solution?

Comment: Hi! I have updated the questions so have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Peter not sure if you ever figured this out but basically you have to use a .downloadTask instead of a .dataTask with your URLSession.  That is likely why your current solution isn't working.  The inclination may be to think "It's not a download task" but its just a matter of schematics.  Think of download as the response from the server (e.g. 200 "Success").  You can still POST using this method.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I am still stuck with this problem, I tried .dataTask in this example if I remember. I will try to use .downloadTask as you mentioned, we will see :)